# < hostname[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 550 5.1.1 <alias@domain.tld> User doesn't exist: alias@domain.tld

Tags: postfix, postgresql, dovecot

This is the setup of my mailserver:
Big picture: MTA: Postfix 2.11.3 - MDA: Dovecot 2.2.13 - DB: Postgres 9.4.10 - OS: Debian 8 Jessie, kernel 3.16.0-4

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_queue_lifetime = 1d
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f “$SENDER” -a “$RECIPIENT”
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 1800s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 1d
message_size_limit = 0
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
mydestination = _hostname_, .... , localhost
myhostname = _hostname_
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
plaintext_reject_code = 550
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks, cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr
postscreen_bare_newline_enable = no
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_cache_cleanup_interval = 24h
postscreen_cache_map = proxy:btree:$data_directory/postscreen_cache
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.2*7 dnsbl.inps.de=127.0.0.2*7 bl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.2*5 bl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[10;11;12]*4 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.10*8 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.5*6 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.7*3 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.8*2 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.6*2 dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.9*2 zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[10;11]*8 zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[4..7]*6 zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.3*4 zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.2*3 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.2*3 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.4*1 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.1.2*1 wl.mailspike.net=127.0.0.[18;19;20]*-2 hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.1*-2
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 8
postscreen_dnsbl_ttl = 5m
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
postscreen_greet_banner = $smtpd_banner
postscreen_greet_ttl = 2d
postscreen_greet_wait = 3s
postscreen_non_smtp_command_enable = no
postscreen_pipelining_enable = no
queue_run_delay = 300s
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 10s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = ${stress?1}${stress:5}
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org, reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth_dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/mail_certs/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/mail_certs/key.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 104
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd

# Postscreen on Port 25/tcp, filters zombies (spam machines) on first level with lowest costs.
##smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen

smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
smtp    unix    -       -       n       -       -       smtp
smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd

dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy

# For mail submitting users. Authenticated clients and known networks only.
submission     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd 
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes 
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth_dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    #-o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
    -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject 
    #-o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,defer_unauth_destination
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject


#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp -v
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#

dovecot   unix   -   n   n   -   -   pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}


# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
```

My virtaul lookup tables (without connection parameters ;) - connection works )

virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_alias_maps.cf

```
query = SELECT maildir FROM mail.mail_view_users_maildir WHERE username='%s'
```

virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf

```
query = SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM mail.mail_view_users_maildir WHERE domain='%s'
```

virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/psql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

```
query = SELECT destination FROM mail.mail_view_forwardings WHERE source='%s'
```

table mail.mail_view_users_maildir:

```
maildir     pass    username    domain
alias-1_domain.tld/ {SHA}123456 alias-1@domain.tld  domain.tld
```

table mail.mail_view_forwardings:

```
source  destination
alias-2@domain.tl   dalias-1@domain.tld
```

doveconf -n

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-lmtp.log
lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes
lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes
mail_gid = 5000
mail_location = maildir:~/var/mail/%u/Maildir
mail_uid = 5000
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Archiv {
    special_use = \Archive
  }
  mailbox Archive {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Archive
  }
  mailbox Archives {
    special_use = \Archive
  }
  mailbox "Deleted Messages" {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Entwürfe {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox "Gelöschte Objekte" {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  mailbox Gesendet {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Gesendete Objekte" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Papierkorb {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
  separator = /
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = imap lmtp
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth_dovecot {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  executable = lmtp -L
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener lmtp {
    mode = 0666
  }
  user = vmail
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/mail_certs/cert.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/mail_certs/key.pem
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
  postmaster_address = postmaster@obg-it.de
}
```

dovecot-sql.conf.ext:

```
driver = pgsql

connect = "host=localhost dbname=serveradmin user=mailserver_manage password=veryverysecret"

password_query = SELECT pass AS password, username AS user, 'maildir:/var/vmail/' || maildir AS userdb_mail, '/var/vmail/' || maildir AS userdb_home, 5000 AS userdb_uid, 5000 AS userdb_gid FROM mail.mail_view_users_maildir WHERE username = '%u'

user_query = SELECT '/var/vmail/' || maildir AS home, 5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid FROM mail.mail_view_users_maildir WHERE username = '%u'
```

This is my setup.
Sending an email from another server to alias-2@domain.tld causes:

```
Feb 22 23:46:03 h2410715 postfix/postscreen[22824]: CONNECT from [68.135.28.22]:59903 to [_**my_ip**_]:25
Feb 22 23:46:03 h2410715 postfix/postscreen[22824]: PREGREET 12 after 0.17 from [68.135.28.22]:59903: EHLO admin\r\n
Feb 22 23:46:03 h2410715 postfix/postscreen[22824]: DISCONNECT [68.135.28.22]:59903
Feb 22 23:46:43 h2410715 postfix/postscreen[22824]: CONNECT from [_**sender_ip**_]:47838 to [_**my_ip**_]:25
Feb 22 23:46:43 h2410715 postfix/postscreen[22824]: PASS OLD [_**sender_ip**_]:47838
Feb 22 23:46:43 h2410715 postfix/smtpd[22838]: connect from _**hostname_of_sender**_[_**sender_ip**_]
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/smtpd[22838]: warning: 137.169.169.81.dnsbl.njabl.org: RBL lookup error: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=137.169.169.81.dnsbl.njabl.org type=A: Host not found, try again
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/smtpd[22838]: 1B0686E007D: client=_**hostname_of_sender**_[_**sender_ip**_]
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/cleanup[22850]: 1B0686E007D: message-id=<58AE14BB.9050506@_**hostname_of_sender**_>
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/qmgr[21228]: 1B0686E007D: from=<webmaster@_**hostname_of_sender**_>, size=819, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/smtpd[22838]: disconnect from _**hostname_of_sender**_[_**sender_ip**_]
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: name_mask: all
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv4 addresses
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv6 addresses
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: process generation: 263 (263)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: match_string: debug_peer_list ~? debug_peer_list
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: match_string: fast_flush_domains ~? debug_peer_list
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: match_string: fast_flush_domains ~? fast_flush_domains
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: name_mask: canonical
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: name_mask: virtual
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: name_mask: dns
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: host name lookup methods: dns
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: auto_clnt_create: transport=local endpoint=private/scache
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: connection established
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: master_notify: status 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: deliver_request_initial: send initial status
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr status = 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: flags
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: flags
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 3
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: queue_name
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: queue_name
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: active
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: queue_id
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: queue_id
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 1B0686E007D
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: offset
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: offset
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 681
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: size
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: size
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 819
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: nexthop
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: nexthop
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: encoding
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: encoding
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: (end)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: sender
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: sender
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: webmaster@_**hostname_of_sender**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: envelope_id
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: envelope_id
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: (end)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: ret_flags
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: ret_flags
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: time
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: time
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 0xSuWAAAAADwnQ4AAAAAAOYUrlgAAAAAngIEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: log_client_name
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: log_client_name
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: _**hostname_of_sender**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: log_client_address
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: log_client_address
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: _**sender_ip**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: log_client_port
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: log_client_port
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 47838
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: log_protocol_name
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: log_protocol_name
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: ESMTP
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: log_helo_name
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: log_helo_name
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: h1617120.stratoserver.net
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: sasl_method
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: sasl_method
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: (end)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: sasl_username
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: sasl_username
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: (end)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: sasl_sender
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: sasl_sender
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: (end)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: log_ident
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: log_ident
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 1B0686E007D
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: rewrite_context
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: rewrite_context
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: remote
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: recipient_count
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: recipient_count
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 1
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: (end)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: original_recipient
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: original_recipient
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: _**alias-2@domain.tld**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: recipient
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: recipient
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: _**alias-2@domain.tld**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: offset
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: offset
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 651
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: dsn_orig_rcpt
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: dsn_orig_rcpt
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: rfc822;_**alias-2@domain.tld**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: notify_flags
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: notify_flags
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: lmtp socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: (end)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: deliver_request_get: file active/1B0686E007D
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: deliver_message: from webmaster@_**hostname_of_sender**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: global TLS level: none
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: ctable_locate: install entry key private/dovecot-lmtp:_**hostname**_:0:
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: smtp_connect_unix: trying: private/dovecot-lmtp...
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: match_hostname: _**hostname**_ ~? 127.0.0.1
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: match_hostaddr: private/dovecot-lmtp ~? 127.0.0.1
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: match_list_match: _**hostname**_: no match
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: match_list_match: private/dovecot-lmtp: no match
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 220 _**hostname**_ Dovecot ready.
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: > _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: LHLO _**hostname**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 250-_**hostname**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 250-8BITMIME
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 250 PIPELINING
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: server features: 0x7 size 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: Using LMTP PIPELINING, TCP send buffer size is 212992, PIPELINING buffer size is 4096
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: > _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: MAIL FROM:<webmaster@_**hostname_of_sender**_>
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: > _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: RCPT TO:<_**alias-2@domain.tld**_>
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: > _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: DATA
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 250 2.1.0 OK
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 550 5.1.1 <_**alias-2@domain.tld**_> User doesn't exist: _**alias-2@domain.tld**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: connect to subsystem private/bounce
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr nrequest = 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr flags = 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr queue_id = 1B0686E007D
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr original_recipient = _**alias-2@domain.tld**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr recipient = _**alias-2@domain.tld**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr offset = 651
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr dsn_orig_rcpt = rfc822;_**alias-2@domain.tld**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr notify_flags = 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr status = 5.1.1
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr diag_type = smtp
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr diag_text = 550 5.1.1 <_**alias-2@domain.tld**_> User doesn't exist: _**alias-2@domain.tld**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr mta_type = dns
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr mta_mname = _**hostname**_
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr action = failed
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr reason = host _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <_**alias-2@domain.tld**_> User doesn't exist: _**alias-2@domain.tld**_ (in reply to RCPT TO command)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: private/bounce socket: wanted attribute: status
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: status
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute value: 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: private/bounce socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: input attribute name: (end)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: 1B0686E007D: to=<_**alias-2@domain.tld**_>, relay=_**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=19, delays=18/0.04/0.09/0.12, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <_**alias-2@domain.tld**_> **User doesn't exist:** _**alias-2@domain.tld**_ (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=120 enable_deadline=0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 554 5.5.1 No valid recipients
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: > _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: RSET
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: > _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: QUIT
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=20 enable_deadline=0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 250 2.0.0 OK
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: < _**hostname**_[private/dovecot-lmtp]: 221 2.0.0 OK
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: name_mask: resource
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: name_mask: software
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: deliver_request_final: send: "" 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr status =
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr diag_type =
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr diag_text =
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr mta_type =
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr mta_mname =
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr action =
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr reason =
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: send attr status = 0
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: master_notify: status 1
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/lmtp[22853]: connection closed
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/cleanup[22850]: 7BF766E0081: message-id=<20170222224702.7BF766E0081@_**hostname**_>
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/bounce[22860]: 1B0686E007D: sender non-delivery notification: 7BF766E0081
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/qmgr[21228]: 7BF766E0081: from=<>, size=2984, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 22 23:47:02 h2410715 postfix/qmgr[21228]: 1B0686E007D: removed
```

Why is says User doesn#t exists? What is wrong with the lookup?